AXIS2- Receive SOAP response despite exception
I can send a request to a specific endpoint using SoapUI and get a response similar to the example response below.
<soap:Envelopexmlns:soap='http: schemas.xmlsoap.org soap envelope'> 
<soap:Header> </soap:Header> 
<soap:Body>  
<soap:Fault>   
<faultcode xmlns:_ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">_ns0:FailedAuthentication</faultcode>   
<faultstring>Errorcode12345: Wrong user password detected for account ' user123'< faultstring>
<detail>Errorcode12345: Wrong user password detected for account 'user123'</detail>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope> 

However, when I send the same request to that SOAP endpoint with my AXIS2 application, I get an "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault" exception thrown by the "_operationClient.execute(true);" method in my generated method stub class.
This exception only contains an error message in the "message" attribute: "Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorised". However, I would like to get the value of the "faultstring" attribute, which is not available in the AxisFault object, but only in the soap response.
Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?
